# How to replace '_' by space in emacs

Tags: emacs

I have a text file which I am only able to look that there is an underscore between some words only using emcas editor but not other editors such as vi. I do not know how to use emacs but I wanted to replace these underscores "_" by space in the emacs editor automated fashion. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that those underscore aren't really underscore, but non breaking space ([U+00A0 unicode char](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)), that Emacs show as underscore with a different color. You probably don't need to replace them, but if this is really needed, just use `M-x replace-string` and kill and yank one of those non-breaking space in the string to be replaced.

Comment: Thank you so much. The Killing and yanking does the job. Superb!!

Comment: How to kill all the occurrences at once, I have 1000s of those unicode chars. The above kill and yank only kills one line.

Comment: I worked it out. I just need to select all text that I need to do a global kill/yank.

Comment: Just kill and yank one of this space, and replace the others.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the `M-x` key-combination (that is, hold meta key - alt on windows - and hit x) type replace-string and hit enter. You can then type [underscore] enter [space] enter.

In Emacs notation:

`M-x replace-string RET _ RET " "`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, some how it does not able to replace it. This is the type of file that I am taking: "TA FILE 000000001             ARCI"  If you open the above text first inserting in a test file in emacs you will see the underscores which I can not able to replace using your command. May be the characters between 000000001 and ARCI are not underscore but other types of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Should the previous answer not solve it: Remember that as a coding system error. Check with C-x = if it's char 95.
If not, check variables coding-system-for-read, coding-system-for-write, buffer-file-coding-system

Finally, get emacs core developers at help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org

Comment: Thank you also Andreas for your further comments but as I said Remi's kill and yank did the trick.